# How can we prove this integral inequality ? $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left|\frac{\sin{(2n+1)t}}{\sin{t}}\right|dt<\pi\left(1+\frac{\ln{n}}{2}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, integral-inequality

Use this 
$$\dfrac{1}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos{(kx)}=\dfrac{\sin{\left(n+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)x}}{2\sin{\dfrac{x}{2}}},x\neq 2m\pi,m\in\mathbb{Z}$$

to show that
$$\int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\left|\dfrac{\sin{(2n+1)t}}{\sin{t}}\right|dt<\pi\left(1+\dfrac{\ln{n}}{2}\right)\text{ for }n\ge 3$$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question? What is the context of the question; where did the question arise?

Comment: Now, I know this methods can't prove it. we must use Jordan inequality to prove it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all $x$,
$$
\left|\frac{\sin((2n+1)x)}{\sin(x)}\right|=\left|\sum_{k=-n}^{n}e^{i2kx}\right|\le2n+1
$$
Note that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-n}^{n}e^{i2kx}=1+2\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(2kx)$.

For $0\le x\le\pi/2$, we have $\sin(x)\ge2x/\pi$. Therefore,
$$
\left|\frac{\sin((2n+1)x)}{\sin(x)}\right|\le\frac\pi{2x}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\left|\frac{\sin((2n+1)x)}{\sin(x)}\right|\,\mathrm{d}x
&\le\int_0^{\pi/(4n+2)}(2n+1)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{\pi/(4n+2)}^{\pi/2}\frac\pi{2x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac\pi2+\frac\pi2\log\left(2n+1\right)
\end{align}
$$
For $n\ge3$, $2n+1\le\frac73n$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac\pi2+\frac\pi2\log\left(2n+1\right)
&\le\frac\pi2\left(1+\log\left(\frac73\right)+\log(n)\right)\\[6pt]
&\le\pi\left(1+\frac{\log(n)}{2}\right)
\end{align}
$$